# How to enable/disable CSRF in Spring at runtime?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, csrf

I have following class which has CSRF if/else condition. I read this flag from property file and I can change the flag value using /refresh end point. :

```
    @Order(-1)
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SomeConfigClass extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                 String csrfFlag = somePropertyFile.getCsrfFlag();
                 if(isCsrfEnable){
                      http.csrf()....some other code
                 }else {
                      http.csrf().disable();
                 }
            }
    }
```

Problem : 
So when I debug the code, I come to know that this class only calls once when Spring container is getting UP. After that if will not be called. So even after changing CSRF flag to false, which intend to switch off the CSRF flag, won't work & CSRF check will be there.

To avoid this, I need to restart/restage the app so that container will then pick up the fresh configurations from property files which may cause the downtime to application.
Can anybody has better solution of this problem ?

Goal :
CSRF disable/enable flag should be externalized.
One can switch the flag and enable/disable CSRF without restarting/re-stagging the app.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use csrf protection matcher to implement the same.

You need to write CSRFProtectionMatcher.

```
 http.csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new CustomCsrfProtectionMatcher())
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
```

CustomCsrfProtectionMatcher.java

```
public class CustomCsrfProtectionMatcher implements RequestMatcher {


    @Override
    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
      //based on the logic..
      //You can store flag in DB or properties or XML File
      //Please note that for every request this flag will be checked.You can choose a 
      //better way to implement this
      return true/false;
    }
}
```

I personally recommend to keep in app.properties rather than checking it per request.

Comment: Currently I am doing that only. I have written custom matcher which checks every request and from property file I am taking flag of CSRF which will be either true or false.

Comment: But your configure method executes only when application is started..But "CustomCsrfProtectionMatcher " is request matcher which executes per request .. Try to implement the code and debug it

Comment: As I said in my first comment, that solution is what I am using now. But I want the solution of problem which I have mentioned in question.